# C++ syntax questions (linked list)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm looking at some sample code that answers the question: remove all elements from a linked list of integers that have value **val.**

The first line of the code is `if (!head) return NULL;`. What does the `(!head)` mean? I'm assuming it means `(head == NULL)`, but is this standard for anytime I'd like to say something like `(head == NULL)`?

---

```
while (h->next){
        if (h->next->val == val){
            h->next = h->next->next;
```

For this section of code, why is it okay to not include the `!= NULL` part? (e.g. `(h->next != NULL)` ) Is that part implied in the statement without having to explicitly state it?

Comment: It means negate the expression. you might think of it as NOT. This isn't about a linked list. Most languages have this unary operator .

Comment: This is C++ fundamentals. You should be able to find extensive discussion of this, and other features of C++ in any good C++ book, which will give you more complete information than you could get asking complete strangers on the intertubes.

Comment: In short, anything that is equivalent to `0` is interpreted as `false`, anything else as `true`. `!` inverts this. Probably not an exact explanation, but IMO a useful rule of thumb. It has always worked for me.

Comment: As @SamVarshavchik already indicated, you would do well to read a good textbook about C++, so you won't have to ask questions about such basic things like this.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, I agree I should definitely go back and reread a C++ fundamentals textbook, and I understand this was a very basic question. But there are also many ways to give advice without being degrading to someone who is just trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `!` is the boolean negation operation.  It `(!head)` is basically `head == 0` or `head == false`.
For the seond part:

Zero is false, and NULL is (almost) always zero, so `while(h->next)` is basically equivalent `while(h->next != NULL)`

Comment: `NULL` *is* always `0`, as far as I know.

Comment: The NULL macro is actually always 0. It can be defined by the implementation of just a 0.